# Invoke anonymous event handler using reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have implemented my own event registration  for a client-server UI framework, much like in ASP.NET. I store an event's name (e.g. "`Click`") in a dictionary and as the value I remember

`oEventHandler.Method.DeclaringType.AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString() + "." + oEventHandler.Method.Name.`

Then to reinvoke the event handlers later on, I recreate the delegate:

```
var oEventHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( BLUIEventHandler ), oPage, sEventMethod, false )
```

and invoke it on the page:

```
oEventHandler.Invoke( oPage, this, oEventArgs );
```

This works fine for event handlers that are part of the ASPX page, like

```
var oTheButton = new UIButton();
oTheButton.Click += this.HandleClick;
private void HandleClick() {}
```

but fails for anonymous delegates:

```
var oTheButton = new UIButton();
oTheButton.Click += delegate {/* Will never be called. */};
```

The resulting string for a non-anonymous delegate is:

```
"MyTest.Rene.UI.Foo, BDRS, Version=8.10.1.19703, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.HandleClick"
```

For an anonymous delegate it is:

```
"MyTest.Rene.UI.Foo+<>c__DisplayClass1, MyTest, Version=8.10.1.17866, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.<OnInitializeLayout>oTheButton__0"
```

However when I try to recreate the anonymous delegate, I get a binding error.
Is there a way to get back to the anonymous delegate and invoke it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is never going to work for the general case of anonymous methods, since there is a *very* good chance that there are captured variables involved, and you will not know the values to capture (plus you have changed the nature: the original closure *could update the captured variables* - they aren't isolated copies).

Personally, I think you should store the `Delegate` instance - not the name. `EventHandlerList` is a typical way of implementing this (along with unique `object` keys per event).

Comment: But is the Delegate instance serializable? If the event handler is on an ASPX page, the page gets unloaded after rendering is done. So I cannot store a reference, it will be gone. How does EventHandlerList deal with that?

Comment: @Krumelur it doesn't, as such. Personally, I wouldn't be looking at serialization *at all* here. A request is isolated; treat it as such.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. Hence the string representation. That's also how ASP.NET does it. I have to try if it supports anonymous delegates.

Comment: I just retried with ASP.NET and the approach really is different there: you have to rewire the events everytime, otherwise nothing will fire. I was not aware of that. Learned something! :-) I accept your answer because of the implications you noted regarding captured variables, but I keep on investigating.